# Default value format on Django DateField

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to specify a default date in a Django model, for example:

```
from datetime import date

class A(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today())
```

This works and I can see the default date in a `ModelForm`, but when I change the form input_format to `%d-%m-%Y`, the default date never appears in the field.

I've also tried:

```
from datetime import date

class A(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

This doesn't work either. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is a difference between the *content* and its representation. You can not set the *representation* in a model, but you can *render* the data according to certain fromat in a template for example.

Comment: Furthermore `default=date.today()` will *not* work, since it will add the day at which the server started, so if the server runs for three days, it will still use that day, not the day when you *construct* a model.

Comment: So, how can I set a default date and show it in the form by default with the format: "%d-%m-%Y"?

Comment: those are *two* separate problems. The first is solved at the model layer, the latter at the template layer (or form layer in case of a form).

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here:

1. the `DateField(default=today.today())` will *not* work, since then the function will be evaluated *eagerly*, and then the default value is thus the result of that function call. As a result the default value is *not* calculated when constructing a new object, and hence eventually will be different; and
2. the representation of a `DateField`. Now the *model* layer does *not* specify a representation, it only specifies how to *store* values in the database, and defines functions on a model.

We can solve the first problem by passing a *reference* to the `today` function, like:

```
from datetime import date

class A(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)    # no ()
```

As for the *representation*, you should specify the format in the *template*, for example with the [**`date`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date), like:

```
<!--  template.html -->
{{ some_a.date|date:'d-m-Y' }}
```

Or in a form with:

```
# app/forms.py

class AForm(ModelForm):
    date = DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'])
    class Meta:
       model = A
```

Comment: It works, and now I can validate the form with this date format. But after adding the input_formats, the date field is empty in the form instead of showing the default_date as before.

Comment: @P.Rodoreda: can you edit your question with the relevant (parts of the) view/form/model?

Comment: What does **no ()** do? I wonder if I should use it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) setting in your Django project settings, this will allow you to make `date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` be accepted by your model field; however, the **DateField** is stored in your database as the native column of the same type and not as a string with a specific format. There is a difference between storing the data and representing it in your forms, templates or DRF serializers. I really recommend keeping the default format for the database and present the data in the format you want by using the [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format) setting to *d-m-Y* that will take care of presenting your dates in that format as long as the **USE_L10N** setting is False.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the same format for display and input, you have to specify input_formats and format(in widget) respectively. for example

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
deadline = forms.DateTimeField(
    input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p', ], # input format
    widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p"), # initial display format
)
```

Comment: This code is wrong. The question is about models.Model, not forms.ModelForm

Comment: "those are two separate problems. The first is solved at the model layer, the latter at the template layer (or form layer in case of a form). "– 
Willem Van Onsem